# how check if doc was updated using updateOne() [mongoose,React , Node js, Mongodb]

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

here is my updating code apparently this works but I have no clue as to how to programmatic check if it had worked, I had an idea of storing the field  want to update in temp variable before updating and then compare it against updatedDoc but t seemed odd I wonder if there is a simpler way

```
router.post('/update',async(req,res)=>{
    const {id,addresses}=  req.body
    try {      
        const targetDoc=await UserModel.findOne({_id:id});

        const updates = { addresses};
        const updateResponse = await targetDoc.updateOne(updates);
        // need to check for succes here 


        const updatedDoc = await UserModel.findOne({_id:id});
        res.sendStatus(200)


    } catch (error) {
       console.log(error)
    }
})
```

Comment: Take a look at https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-updateOne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to check if a document **can** be updated is to check **before** it's updated. That way, if any of the assertions you've made before the update are passing, then you'll know it's been successfully updated:

```js
router.post('/update',async(req,res)=>{
  try { 
    // move this statement inside the try block; otherwise if "id" or "addresses"
    // is missing from req.body, it'll throw an unhandled destructure error
    const { id, addresses} = req.body;
    
    // make sure the id is present
    if (!id) throw String("Invalid request. You must supply a user id to update!");
    
    /* 
      I'm not sure how "addresses" is structured, but if you expect
      it to be an object, then make assertions against an object with structure:
      if(!object || object.length <= 0 || !object.name || !object.city ...etc)

      if it's an array, then make assertions that it's not empty...
    */
    if (addresses assertions are invalid)
      throw String("Invalid request. The addresses you've provided are not valid! Please try again.");       

    /* 
      If the above passes the req.body assertions, then the only thing  
      that can fail here is if "id" is invalid. If it's invalid, then Mongoose
      will throw an error if "updateOne" doesn't find the document; 
      otherwise, you'll know the document has been successfully updated.    

      Optionally, you can manually handle "id" errors by finding and throwing
      an error if the document is empty BEFORE attempting to update, 
      for example...

      const existingUser = await UserModel.findOne({ _id: id });
      if (!existingUser) throw String("Unable to locate that user to update.");

      await existingUser.update(addresses);
      await existingUser.save();
    */
    await UserModel.updateOne({ _id: id }, { addresses });

    // if the above is successful, then the client should receive this
    // message:
    res.status(200).send("Successfully updated user!");
  } catch (error) {
    // if any of the above assertions are unsuccessful, then the 
    // client should receive an error message:
    res.status(400).send(error.toString());
  }
});
```

On a side note, always return a response! Even if it's just `res.end()`. Failing to do so, will result in a hung request/unhandled promise.

Comment: thanks for the clear answer I can vote now because I don't have that privilege yet but sure  will when I can

Comment: also about the assertions , on the client side I am making sure no api calls are being sent unless the address object is valid

Comment: It's easy to circumvent the client and send a request directly to the API. Make assertions on both client and API.